# Random variables and the topology of weak convergence

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions

To see what's going on, I am trying to translate the idea of topology of weak convergence on a random variable setting, just to get some concrete intuition. This is what I have got so far (where the topological setting is the standard one from where to start, and the other one is my translation in *concrete* terms).

---

**Topological setting:**

- $X$ metrizable topological space,
- $\mathcal{B} (X)$ Borel $\sigma$-algebra,
- $\Delta (X)$ set of all probability measures over $\mathcal{B} (X)$,
- $C_b (X)$ set of all continuous bounded functionals on $X$.
- $w^*$ topology on $\Delta (X)$ s.t. for all $f \in C_b (X)$, $\mu \mapsto \int f d \mu$ is $w^*$-continuous.

**Example of a Probabilistic setting:**

- $X$ represents the faces of two rolled dice that can show up,
- $\mathcal{B} (X)$ is the set of possible events associated with $X$,
- $\Delta (X)$ set of all probability measures over $\mathcal{B} (X)$,
- $C_b (X)$ is the set of all random variables on $X$, such as the random variable $f =$ sum of the two numbers that appear.
- $w^*$ topology on $\Delta (X)$ s.t. for all $f \in C_b (X)$, $\mu \mapsto \int f d \mu$ is $w^*$-continuous, which means that – by fixing a random variable – there is a functional that maps the probability measure $\mu \in \Delta (X)$ to the expected value of the random variable $f$ according to $\mu$.

**Questions**

Apparently, as I found out in [this pdf](http://www.columbia.edu/~ww2040/framechno.pdf), the standard way of looking at those things is slightly different. Indeed, random variable should enter in the picture as something that is just used in order to talk about the convergence of $\mu_n$, without directly using probability measures. But still my question remains the following:

1. Can we use my alternative way of looking at those things as a sound one, even if not completely standard?
2. If the intuition is correct, in this case – for a fair dice – we have only one possible probability measure $\mu$, right?

---

Any feedback is most welcome.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm not an expert in the domain that that pdf is speaking to. I'm familiar with the situation where X has no metric, but clearly, with the metric, this opens up new topologies to consider on $\Delta (X)$. I can definitely say that for a fair dice there is a single probability measure, but I would strongly caution you: moving from the finite to the infinite case is a big move. I think if you want to understand that text you link, you should try to understand it on the writers terms. They chose them for a reason, they have familiarity with the subject..

Comment: Well, first of all thanks a lot. Actually, that pdf is not my reference in any way. I was simply madly going around on the Net to get some indirect feedback and to try to find some confirmation of my idea (side-effects of being a self-learner when I don't get feedbacks here... :-) ).Thus, by putting that pdf aside, may I ask you if after all my way of translating things to get intuition is correct?